# Issue with System.Spatial assembly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I recently attempted to run my application locally to test something,but I couldn't due to an assembly issue.  Specifically:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Spatial, Version=5.2.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

So, I went poking around here, and found a reference to either manually add things to config files, or uninstall and reinstall things via NuGet. We do not use NuGet to handle anything, so I am wary of changing the application to start doing so.  Thus, I began editing config files to try and resolve this issue.
I added the following lines, and resolve the unable to load System.Spatial issue:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.0.0" newVersion="5.5.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

but now I get this message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Edm' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Maybe the publicKeyToken is inaccurate with the version change?  I am not sure what happened to break the assemblies in the first place (since I did not modify the code, and do not use NuGet to update packages for this project), or why the manifest is off.

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening here, how it can be caused, and other possible steps I can take to correct it?

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by deleting the contents of the obj folder in the project and rebuilding.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. Remove the System.Spatial(version 5.6.3) reference and add the System.Spatial(version 5.6.4) will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using a shared library installed by hand(using gac-util), if so you can include the library by clicking references->Add reference->Browse then browse to this location
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\yourlibrary
Anyway maybe you should avoid changing .config files unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: I attempted this method.  I found the System.Spatial library at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Spatial.

However, this did not resolve the issue.  

If my research is accurate, the System.Spatial.dll is loaded by Microsoft.Data.Edm (which is why this library is referenced in the config file changes), so I am not attempting to use anything in System.Spatial directly, though something is used.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @AndrewS.Giles maybe referencing Microsoft.Data.Edm will solve the problem.

Comment: I have Microsoft.Data.Edm referenced in the project already.  A class from that library that is being used is attempting to load System.Spatial at run time, even though it is not referenced; and is apparently not finding the proper version (even though it is installed).  I have also attempted to add System.Spatial to the project, to help resolve the issue, and that has failed as well.

Comment: @AndrewS.Giles maybe installing the two libraries again will solve the issue, I think the versions should be compatible so installing them together(instead of separated)would be better, otherwise sorry but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

The minimal number of required packages for an MVC 4 project should be about 20. If you have a lot of unused references such as more than likely the System.Spatial reference, just do this:

1. Open packages.config to see all packages
2. Save a copy of original packages.config for reference
3. Open the Package Manager Console
4. Run at PM> Uninstall-Package System.Spatial
5. Build and run or deploy to see if problem goes away. If reference is really needed, it won't build.
6. If project won't build without reference, PM> Install-Package System.Spatial  -Version [version] (using version number from copy of packages.config)

Nuget is nice for managing legitimate updates to a package, but is a pain when many unused packages get installed and a single dependency in last years version of MVC or .NET throws you into DLL hell.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing of the above has helped me.
After a day spent for this issue, the solution for me was simply the following two steps:

- open Package Manager Console window
- enter `PM> Install-Package    WindowsAzure.Storage -Version [your_version_number]-preview -Pre`

this is supposed to automatically **fit all dependencies to your current azure version**.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the reference in my project because it was not being used. That fixed it for me.